# how set time-to-live for column in Cassandra with Hector?

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

how set time-to-live for column in Cassandra 1.1.6 with Hector?  i tried find any method for this problem but nothing founded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use setTtl method of HColumn in hector

```
column.setTtl(ttl);
```